# Facebook post data has empty privacy field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

We are having an issue with one facebook users account where the privacy field returned for his posts are always blank. I have tried reproducing this with my account or a test account, but in all cases the privacy is filled in. Here is a sample using the graph api tool (some fields removed for brevity):

```
{
  "id": "<deleted_for_privacy>", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Joe Blog", 
    "id": "<deleted_for_privacy>"
  }, 
  "story": "Joe Blog added a new photo.", 

  "picture": "<deleted_for_privacy>", 
  "link": "<deleted_for_privacy>", 
  "icon": "<deleted_for_privacy>", 
  "privacy": {
    "value": ""
  }, 
  "type": "photo", 
  "status_type": "added_photos"
},
```

According to the [documentation for privacy the field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/) this should always contain a value.

My initial thoughts was it was related to the blackberry app being used and the old mobile version setting, but posting from the desktop browser results in the same issue.

So what does a blank setting mean? Is it public, private or a bug?

Comment: Sadly, this bug still exists...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is your case, but if the user is posting to a page, event, group or another users's feed, the privacy field is expected to be empty.

See the first note here (not the official fb doc page, I know):

http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/facebook/api/facebook-graph-api/docs/reference/privacy-parameter

Answer (score 0):

> This is by design. You require a page access token or admin user
>   access token to retrieve this field.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/300329193480725/?comment_id=345320875630426