# Determine if object (post, photo, etc) is public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

Is there some reliable way to determine if the post, photo or whatever other FB object is public or not? We crawl FB objects and need a way to check if it safe to publish the data.

For now, I have the same problems:

- for posts as described there -
  [Facebook post data has empty privacy field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891254/facebook-post-data-has-empty-privacy-field)
- for photos as described there -
  http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8226699/check-photo-privacy-for-a-user
  (accepted answer actually works only in a limited cases).

I even submitted a bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/640818855946378

**Upd:** They already closed the ticket as 'By Design':

> "The privacy field is only shown to the owner of the post."

Maybe someone knows some workaround? All we need is to determine if the object is public.

Comment: Although this might entail more work but as you just want to know if the object is public, have you tried accessing the object using your app access token? You can only access the Public data through it, for everything else you will get some error. Check and tell if this solves your main issue

Comment: I haven't tried that. Rate limits concern me. We will have a thousands  of API requests and I don't want application token to be banned. I don't know, but if it's possible to make all calls with one token, then empty fake account can be created and use its token. Do you know something about rate limits per token?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena After some digging, I think rate limits are: 600 calls / 600 seconds per IP, per token. So it seems it's not a good idea to use one token to make all calls.

Comment: Sorry for not posting this earlier but the rate limit is a little higher that what you have found out. Do give [this a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121800/rate-limiting-solution/17122169#17122169). Also, if possible could you post the support for your comment about 600 calls/600 sec/IP

Comment: @AnveshSaxena e.g. this one http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit. It just doesn't feel right to make a lot of queries with one token. Have you tried that? Say, 5M queries with one token?

Comment: That is very old article, the API has since changed a lot of time. And no, I haven't tried 5M queries.. ever. And as I said this might be one of the workaround